# How to initialise a struct-type in the initialisation list?

Tags: c++, struct, initialization, constructor

How can I initilise a structure in the constructor list?

Say:

```
struct St{int x, y};

class Foo
{
public:
Foo(int a = 0, int b = 0) : /*here initilise st_foo out of a and b*/
{}

private:
const St st_foo;
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide a constructor for `struct St` that takes 2 `int` parameters and assigns them to `x` and `y`. Then invoke it in your `Foo` initialization list.

Remember: structs are the same thing as classes except default visibility rules (for structs, default is `public`.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=484&WT.rss_f=Guide&WT.rss_a=Aggregate+Member+Initialization+&WT.rss_ev=a) is an answer in case you want zero initialization for the struct (a solution for c++0x is also pointed out for the general case). It is sufficient to put an empty pair of parentheses after the member's name:

```
Foo() : st_foo()
```